# jqgrid subgrid need to change the plus/minus icons with text message

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

in JQGrid when we enable sub-grid to true by default it displays '+/-' icons to expand/collapse the sub-grid.But in our case we need to update this with a text like view members/hide members.There is an option provided in jqgrid which is subgridoptions where we can only provide the icon classes rather than the text message.Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a two image with these text  "View Members" and "Hide Members".  and use below code to show and hide image in jqgrid header.

```
 $("#" + "img_" + subgrid_table_id).bind("click", function (e) {

                                  var status = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.ExpandODiv').is(":hidden");
                                  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.ExpandODiv').slideToggle();

                                  if (status == true) {
                                      $(this)[0].src = '../Content/images/icon_collapse_jqgrid.png';
                                      BindContractRateGrid($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.batchid').html(), $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.gridname').html() + 1);
                                  }
                                  else {
                                      $(this)[0].src = '../Content/images/icon_expand_jqgrid.png';


                                  }

                              });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we do without creating images